# How to install pydoc on Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, pip, pydoc

I'm trying to install `pydoc` on my Windows system using CMD as administrator.

When I put this command:

```
pip install pydoc
```

I got this error message:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pydoc (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for pydoc

Answer (score 6):

`pip` installs packages from PyPI and there is no [pydoc at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pydoc/). [pydoc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html) is a module from the standard library, that is, it's always available.

Answer (score 5):

Try typing:

```
python -m pydoc
```

to see the help text.